# Reading a file and adding NewLine after every ";"

Tags: python, file

I have a hobby CNC machine with a strangely written software. In order to use it, I need to take my file that is outputted by a CAD software and add a new line (CRLF) after every ";". I wanted to make a python script that would do this instead, but I can't get it to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
import os
import sys

if not (len(sys.argv) == 2 and os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1])):
    print(__doc__)
    sys.exit(1)

file_in = open(sys.argv[1], "r+")
currentChar = file_in.read(1)
i = 0
while not currentChar:
    if (currentChar == ";"):
        file_in.seek(i)
        file_in.write("\n")
    currentChar = file_in.read(1)
    i += 1
file_in.close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether your code is correct, but reading and writing at the same time from/to a file can introduce problems (can mess up the R/W pointers). You should read all the file contents (at once), into a string, replace each `;` occurrence by `;\n`, then write the sting back to another file. It will also work faster. Of course this doesn't apply to *TB* sized files :).

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an error or the wrong output? If it's CRLF, you may need `'\r\n'` instead of just `'\n'`. You can also read the file into a string and to a replace. `contents = file_in.read().replace(';', ';\r\n')`

Comment: Also, `while not currentChar:` doesn't make much sense. You only want to process the character if it's not there?

Comment: @glibdud - is that a way of saying `while not eof` in Python?  Does `.read(1)` return a null when it reaches the end of file?

Comment: @AgapwIesu Yes, but the proper way to implement that would be `while currentChar:`. Adding the `not` will cause the loop to never run unless the file is empty.

Comment: but bottom line, if you open a file for read-write, and try to write to it at a specific location, wouldn't you be overwriting the contents of the next character?  I don't know Python, so...?  But if it is that way, you need to open it for read, read the whole contents, replace the ";" like @pault suggests (minus the `\r`), and then write the contents back out to the file.  Right?

Comment: @glibdud - you are totally right about that.  Didn't catch that.  Cezar, start by changing that like glibdud suggests, and you will probably have a better result (except that the character after the ";" will get replaced by the newline).

Comment: @AgapwIesu line endings always confuse me. If the OP wanted CRLF, isn't `\r\n` the appropriate thing to write? Or does the file encoding automatically take care of that? My understand was that `\r` = CR and `\n` = LF. I'd love some clarification in this.

Comment: Did it like CritiFati/pault/FlyingTeller said and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by CristiFati's comment, you should read the file, close it and then open it for writing:

```
import sys

file_in = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
content = file_in.read()
file_in.close()
file_out = open(sys.argv[1],'w')
file_out.write(content.replace(';',';\n'))
file_out.close()
```

Optionally you can change the output filename to be something different so that you don't overwrite your original file.